# incomplete type, forward declaration

Tags: c++, struct, forward-declaration

I'm just learning C++ and I'm having a lot of problems. Right now I'm trying to implement a frequency queue with a heap and a hashtable, so I'm trying to make structs for hash table entrys and heap entrys. What I did is...

```
  1 #include<iostream>
  2 #include<string>
  3 #include "freqq.h"
  4
  5 using namespace std;
  6
  7 
  8 
  9
 10 struct _hashEntry {
 11   string word;
 12   int heapPstn;
 13 };
 14
 15 struct _heapEntry {
 16   int frequency;
 17   hashEntry* wordInHash;
 18 };

^^ the .cpp, 
 1 #define FREQQ_H_
  2 #include <string>
  3
  4 using namespace std;
  5
  6 class FreqQ {
  7  public:
  8   struct _heapEntry;
  9   typedef struct _heapEntry heapEntry;
 10
 11   struct _hashEntry;
 12   typedef struct _hashEntry hashEntry;
 13
```

^^ the .h . I've eliminated the other methods for simplicity.

I'm getting the error
invalid use of incomplete type âstruct FreqQ::_heapEntryâ
freqq.h:8:10: error: forward declaration of âstruct FreqQ::_heapEntryâ

And I can't figure out why for the life of me.

Any ideas??

Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is that the compiler thinks the `struct _heapEntry;` forward declared inside class FreqQ is a different `struct _heapEntry` from the one declared in the source file. I think you're trying too hard. You clearly know programming but stick to simpler C++ syntax for now. Lose the typedefs inside `FreqQ`.

Comment: That is what I had tried to do initially, but it produced the same error

Comment: Lose the typedefs and the structs. As alestansis says move those structs into the header file. If it's still not clear post the updated code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand. You're defining your `_hashEntry` and `_heapEntry` structs in the .cpp?

Move the struct declarations to the .h before the `class FreqQ` declaration, where the structs are used.

Comment: Ok I tried that, it now says that hashEntry does not declare a type, at line in the heapEntry struct that uses hashEntry

Comment: You are missing an underscore inside your struct, it should be `_hashEntry` and not `hashEntry`